# Is GestureDetector available on Android 2.1+

Tags: android

I need to know if GestureDetector is backward compatible to 2.1 devices? in terms of supporting Swipe gesture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is.  You can tell because in the [API Docs for Gesture Detector](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.html), it states, "Since: API Level 1".

Each of the methods documented also contains a line saying which API level they were added in.

Comment: does it support swipe since 2.1?